# Pass a table variable using table type into a stored procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have a table employee with around 1000 entries, I have to create a stored procedure which accepts a parameter. The parameter will most likely be of the type which I created 'AS Table'. Upon passing the table variable into the stored procedure, it should update certain values in specific columns and the changes should reflect in the original Employee table.

I tried the following steps:

```
USE testDB
GO

CREATE TYPE dbo.UpdateTableType AS TABLE(Id BIGINT NULL, Designation varchar(50) NULL, Salary varchar(50) NULL)

DECLARE @employeeTable TABLE(Id BIGINT, Designation varchar(50), Salary varchar(50))

INSERT INTO @employeeTable
    VALUES 
        (2, 'Sales', '$8002'),
        (7, 'Sales DPO', '$8007'),
        (9, 'Sales Mgr', '$8009')

Select * from @employeeTable
```

The above is for the table type and the table variable

Now, for the stored procedure I tried,

```
CREATE PROCEDURE updateEmpDetails
    @UpdateType UpdateTableType READONLY
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE dbo.employee
        SET 
            dbo.employee.Designation = @UpdateType.Designation,
            dbo.employee.Salary = @UpdateType.Salary
        WHERE
            @UpdateType.Id = dbo.employee.[Employee ID]
END
```

> Msg 137, Level 16, State 1, Procedure updateEmpDetails, Line 7 [Batch Start Line 2] Must declare the scalar variable "@UpdateType"

Please help me as to where am I going wrong.

I need to update the [Employee Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wbWmC.png) using a stored procedure that accepts table variable.

If possible please provide me with the correct code for the same.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206482/discussion-on-question-by-neelabh-pass-a-table-variable-using-table-type-into-a).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing a table type, So you need to join with it as a table instead.

```
UPDATE e
SET e.Designation = u.Designation,
    e.Salary = u.Salary

FROM dbo.employee e
INNER JOIN @UpdateType u ON e.[Employee ID] = u.Id
```

**FullCode:**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE updateEmpDetails
    @UpdateType UpdateTableType READONLY
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE e
    SET e.Designation = u.Designation,
        e.Salary = u.Salary

    FROM dbo.employee e
    INNER JOIN @UpdateType u ON e.[Employee ID] = u.Id
END
```

Comment: what does 'e' here refer to?

Comment: it's a table alias according to `dbo.employee`

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell, the update statement should read

```
CREATE PROCEDURE updateEmpDetails
    @UpdateType UpdateTableType READONLY
AS
BEGIN    
    UPDATE 
        e
    SET 
        Designation = u.Designation,
        Salary = u.Salary
    FROM
        dbo.employee AS e
        INNER JOIN @UpdateType AS u ON
            u.Id=e.[Employee ID];
END
```

So join the employee table with the table variable with this way of writing the update statement.

The `e` in the update statement is the table alias assigned to `dbo.employee` in the FROM clause. I could also have written `UPDATE dbo.employee [...]`, that would work as well. Note that the FROM clause can have multiple references to `dbo.employee` (for some more complex statements) in which case you should definitely use the alias to denote which should be used as the anchor for updates. I just always use the alias, makes SQL statements more uniform.